# Windows 10 Python Path Update

Tags: python, path, windows-10

I recently began using Windows 10. Obviously, after the upgrade, my environmental PATH variable migrated to the new OS. On windows 10, I installed Python 3.4. After the install, I updated my PATH variable with:

```
;C:\Python34\Scripts;C:\Python34\python.exe;
```

However, the cmd still does not find the python commands. It would seem as if the PATH variable just plainly was not updated. Any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: You don't want `python.exe` on the path, just the directory containing it.  If you change that second one ` C:\Python34` does it work?

Comment: It works for python, but pip still doesn't function. When I give the command "pip install something" it tells me "Unknown or unsupported command 'install'".

Comment: That error message makes it sound like it can find pip, but pip itself isn't working.  If you just do `pip` by itself what do you get?

Comment: I get "Did not provide a command." But when I cd to the Python34\Scripts dir and run pip it works fine.

Answer (score 5):

Open the command prompt using console.

write command as **python** [Press Enter]

[image]

If it shows the above error of "not recognized" command, don't worry.

Write you Python installed path in below statement, as for me It is **C:\Python34**

```
setx path "%PATH%";C:\Python34"
```

Run the above command on your command prompt as below Screenshot

[image]

Run command **python** again, still shows same error.

Okay, close you command prompt window & open again, type now **python** and press enter, It will now show what you are expecting.

Hope it works!!

Comment: With a new windows update, when typing python/python3 in cmd you are forced to windows store. To fix this you can either use `py` instead of `python` or you can go to "Manage App Execution Aliases" and then disable aliases for python. Finally re-add python to env. variables by ```set PATH=%PATH%;C:\your\path\to\python\```